# How to stop Wing IDE from opening imported modules on exception

Tags: python, wing-ide

I'm setting up Wing IDE to run my code, and have a few libraries imported.  When my code hits an exception, wing'll automatically open up numpy or openpyxl to where the the exception occurred.  How to I prevent Wing from opening up some library that's not the problem?

I dug through the Wing page, and didn't find anything about this in its design

What I'd like:
   When I write bad code, just bring up the errors in the "Exceptions" window

What I'm getting:
   When I write bad code, it opens the library file that threw the exception and highlights it, instead of staying in my crappy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Wing shows you the line where the exception is raised and you can go up the stack by clicking on lines in the exception tool.  We plan on adding an option to show you the line in your code where the library was called.